# printing a 2D array in ocaml

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, ocaml, computer-science

I have written following code in Ocaml to print 2D array:

```
let string_of_float_arr l = String.concat " " (Array.map string_of_float l)

let float_arr_to_string l = String.concat "\n" (Array.map string_of_float_arr l)
```

I am getting error,can anyone please help me in pointing out the error

Comment: String.concat takes a string and a list of strings.. Convert your array of strings to a list of strings.Hint: Array.to_list...

Comment: Array.to_list helps only for 1D array and not 2D array

Comment: Should you really be using map for this exercise? I'd reach for Array.fold_left.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said. I'd reach for Array.fold_left to solve this exercise if the goal is building a string. Here's how you can apply Array.fold_left to a single dimension float array to get the string.

```
let arr = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0|]

let farr_to_string arr =
  Array.fold_left (fun acc elem -> acc ^ (string_of_float elem)) "" arr

let () = print_endline (farr_to_string arr)
```

Now you have to create another function which takes a 2D float array and applies Array.fold_left again.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you just want to print then use Array.iter

```
let arr = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; |]

let () = Array.iter(fun elem -> print_endline (string_of_float elem)) arr
```

Its a simple exercise to use Array.iter on a 2D array of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a custom `pp_` formatter for arrays and then use [`Format.printf`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html#VALprintf) with the `%a` specifier. This has the advantage that with the proper arguments, the function can accommodate different data types in the array as well as different separators.

```
# let pp_array to_t sep out arr =
    arr
    |> Array.to_seq
    |> Seq.map to_t
    |> List.of_seq
    |> String.concat sep
    |> Format.fprintf out "%s";;
val pp_array :
  ('a -> string) -> string -> Format.formatter -> 'a array -> unit =
  <fun>
# Format.printf "%a\n" (pp_array string_of_float " ") [|2.3; 3.4|];;
2.3 3.4
- : unit = ()
# Format.printf "[|%a|]\n" (pp_array string_of_int "; ") [|1; 2; 3; 4|];;
[|1; 2; 3; 4|]
- : unit = ()
```